# Should I use log transformation on Target Encoding values ​to avoid heteroscedasticity?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-model, data-transformation, categorical-encoding, logarithm

The dataset I'm working with contains categorical variables with several classes. To do its pre-processing I chose to use Target Encoder.

With numerical variables I used MinMaxScaler. When training the linear regression model, the residuals I obtained do not follow a normal distribution and are not homoscedastic.

I'm thinking of using the log transformation to see if the assumptions related to the residuals are satisfied. My question is, does it make sense to use the log transformation also on the values ​​that were obtained from the Target Encoder?